# Does the Document TYPE ( or even the way HTML tag is written) affects the javascript engine in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

Does the Document TYPE ( or even the way HTML tag is written) affects the javascript engine in IE9? I am not talking about the rendition but the behavior other than it.

Comment: What in particular is your concern?  Have you noticed some strange behavior?

Comment: An Iframe is created and pseudo-ajax POST is done. On 2nd attempt, it does not work. Perhaps, a caching issue.

Now, I replace the `HTML tag with attributes` with simple <html> tag and everything works fine. I guess, it could be some caching issue.

Comment: @user395881 Well, what you asked is pretty much unrelated. Please create a new question with relevant code. Note that POST requests are never cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The `<!doctype>` is used as rendering mode switch. This is notable especially in Internet Explorer, because this browser maintains (almost) full backwards compatibility in quirks mode, so there's no `getElementsByClassName`, Element Traversal, `addEventListener`, Selection API, ES5 support and many many other things. ES5 support also means changes in parsing so you might experience differences in things not related to DOM.

Always use `<!doctype html>` at the top of your markup, it's simple and provides best cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but there are some differences in DOM support between standards and quirks mode. (e.g. in standards mode the browser does not brokenly support name as id).